# Point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb{S}^2$

Tags: spherical-coordinates, conformal-geometry, compactification

**Question** : How to show that $(\mathbb{R}^2,\delta)$ is **conformal related** with $(\mathbb{S}^2,\sigma)$  ? Here we have

1.1) $\delta$ is just the standard euclidian metric in spherical coordinates;

1.2) $\sigma$ is the standard metric of $\mathbb{S}^2$.

**Example** I know how to do the compactification of $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $\mathbb{S}^3$. We have

2.1) $\sigma=d\psi\otimes d\psi +\sin^2(\psi)d\theta \otimes d\theta + \sin^2(\psi)\sin^2(\theta)d\phi \otimes d\phi$

2.2) $\delta= dr \otimes dr+r^2 d\theta \otimes d\theta + r^2 \sin^2(\theta)d\phi \otimes d\phi$

Thus we set $\sigma=\omega^2 \delta$ where $\omega$ is the **conformal factor** and solve to $\omega,r(\psi)$

**Problem** I tried this same idea to solve my question, but it did not work. I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: What is the definition that those two are conformal related? (In my definition I would have a mapping $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb S^2$)

Comment: I thought this could work just by ignoring $\psi$. Using $\sigma=d\theta \otimes \theta + \sin^2(\theta)d \phi \otimes d \phi$ and $\delta = dr \otimes dr + r^2 d\theta \otimes d\theta$ setting $r=r(\psi)$. But this did not work. Maybe using $\delta=dr \otimes dr+ r^2 d\psi \otimes d \psi$. But that will be pretty arbitrary if work with last $\delta$ but not with the first.

Comment: (M,g) and (M',g') will be conformally related if we have a conformal factor $\omega^2$ such that $g=\omega^2 g'$. Actually, I used that $M$ is conformal compactification of $M'$ if there's a map $\psi: M\rightarrow M' $ such that $ g=(\psi^*)^{-1}(\omega^2 g')'$ (+ some conditions about $\omega$)

Comment: Yep, it seems to work using $ \delta = dr \otimes dr + r ^ 2 d \psi \otimes d \psi $ and then doing the same thing as in the example.